# I am trying to change the color of link using javascript and its not working

Tags: javascript

I have used the following code

```html
<a id="link1" href= "http://www.yahoo.com" onmouseover="document.getElementById('link1').style.color='yellow'">this is a link</a>
```

Is this correct? I am not getting output

Comment: Why do you use JS for this ? CSS is a better way

Comment: Try using css psuedo selectors class.

eg: a:hover {
      color: red;
}

This will change the color of your link to red on hover

Comment: yeah CSS worked .. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To change css you have different solution :

1st :

You can add hover for your div in css file :

```
a:hover { color: blue; }
```

2nd :

You can create a custom JS function in your js file :

```
$("a").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color","blue")
});
```

3rd :

You can add the method directly in the div :

```
<a id="link1" href= "http://www.yahoo.com" onmouseover="this.style.background='#FFFF99';>this is a link</a>
```

If you add the method on the div, you don't have to call getElementById, you already are on the element

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a id="link1" href= "http://www.yahoo.com" onmouseover="this.style.background='#FFFF00'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#FFF'">this is a link</a>
```